# Android SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder not updating bound TextView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SimpleCursorAdapter and I'm attempting to bind a SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to it. Below is the code that I am using.

```
// Setup Cursor and SimpleCursorAdapter, called in Activity onResume()
Cursor userCursor = getUserProfile(userEmail);
mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                R.layout.user_profile,
                userCursor, 
                new String[] { 
                    StackOverFlow.Users.FULL_NAME,
                    StackOverFlow.Users.EMAIL }, 
                new int[] {
                    R.id.txtvwProfileUserFullName,
                    R.id.txtvwProfileOtherUserInfo } ); 
mAdapter.setViewBinder(new UserProfileViewBinder());
```

My UserProfileViewBinder class:

```
private class UserProfileViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
        TextView tv;
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 1: // TODO: Magic Numbers, bad!
            tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtvwProfileUserFullName);
            String userFullName = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            tv.setText(userFullName);
            break;
        case 2: // TODO: Magic Numbers, bad!
            tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtvwProfileOtherUserInfo);
            String userEmail = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            tv.setText(userEmail);
            break;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

## **Issue**

When I load the activity, the TextView's do not get updated with the data from the `userCursor`. I can confirm that `userCursor` is in fact pointing to a valid row in the backing SQLite database, and has data, but the `setViewValue` method in `UserProfileViewBinder` never appears to be executing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or neglecting to include.

As an alternative, I'm doing the following to set the TextView's text:

```
if (mAdapter.getCursor().moveToFirst()) {
    mUserFullName.setText(mAdapter.getCursor().getString(
            StackOverFlow.USER_FULL_NAME));
    mUserOtherInfo.setText(mAdapter.getCursor().getString(
            StackOverFlow.USER_EMAIL));
}
```

But I don't think this will automatically update the TextView's when the cursor data changes. when the `ContentProvider` calls `setNotificationUri` after executing a query, and the REST server call returns and the thread updates the row the cursor is pointing at.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you planing to do other thing besides setting the text on those two `TextViews`? If the answer is no then you have no reason to use the `ViewBinder` as the `SimpleCursorAdapter`, by default, will set the text for you.

Anyway, I don't understand why you used the `columnIndex` parameter  to identify the views and not the id of the view that is passed in. See if this helps:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {        
        if (view.getId() == R.id.txtvwProfileUserFullName) {
            String userFullName = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            ((TextView) view).setText(userFullName);
            return true;
        } else if (view.getId() == R.id.txtvwProfileOtherUserInfo) {
            String userEmail = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            ((TextView) view).setText(userEmail);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```